# on button click image will show lock screen preview and home screen preview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a photo gallery and also one action sheet. images comes from URL on scroll view. so, there is two button in action sheet
1) Lock screen Preview and 2) Home screen preview
click on the button it will show how lock screen will look like and also on home screen button it ll look like home wallpaper.
just preview not to set them..
I dont have idea on it..please help me....

Comment: this would be simple.. u need to mix or use 2 images one upon another..

Answer (score 0):

If i well understand you do this:

Create PreviewViewController and set in viewWillAppera delegate:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

When you want to call preview use this in your ActionSheet delegate method:

```
- (void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet*) actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(buttonIndex == 0) {
        [self presentViewController:preview animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

You can also add cancel button in your PreviewViewController and dismiss view when it clicked:

```
-(IBAction)cancelButtonTaped:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```